# Can a DLNA renderer update all controllers?

Tags: audio, remote-control, dlna, controller

Or can the controllers be configured to poll the renderer to update themselves?

In using JRiver Media Centerto play audio through an Onkyo DAC that supports DLNA.

Means of control include multiple forms of JRiver; desktop, web, and Android apps. Also The Onkyo TX-8160 came with a physical remote, has physical buttons on the unit and provides an app, 'Onkyo remote'.

As long as I stick to JRiver apps OR the Onkyo methods. All is good. However I play music via the Onkyo interfaces, the JRiver apps do not update accordingly. They continue to show the last thing played through them.

My question is. Could the JRiver apps even pool the player to see that it is playing something?

I would think so since the DLNA server is JRiver Media Server.

Comment: I'm guessing that based on your own experience the answer is "no".

Comment: I'm not always so quick to assume that my anecdotal experience is empirical.